# Axios get request with categoryId as body request with react native error 401 || 415

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, get-request

this is the function I use

```
export async function getDishes() {
 

  const url = DishesAuthURL;

  const userToken = newUser.getToken();

  const authStr = "Bearer ".concat(userToken);
  console.log(" ~ file: menu.js:108 ~ getDishes ~ authStr", authStr);

  const response = await axios
    .get(
      url,
      {
        params: {
          categoryId: 1,
        },
      },
      { headers: { Authorization: authStr } }
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(" ~ file: menu.js:108 ~ getDishes ~ error", error);
    });
  console.log(" ~ file: menu.js:112 ~ getDishes ~ response", response);
}
```

When I use the function as above I receive error [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401] --> Which If I understand correctly means that my token expired or maybe wrong

When I set the headers before the params like this

```
export async function getDishes() {
  const url = DishesAuthURL;

  const userToken = newUser.getToken();

  const authStr = "Bearer ".concat(userToken);
  console.log(" ~ file: menu.js:108 ~ getDishes ~ authStr", authStr);

  const response = await axios
    .get(
      url,

      { headers: { Authorization: authStr } },
      {
        params: {
          categoryId: 1,
        },
      }
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(" ~ file: menu.js:108 ~ getDishes ~ error", error);
    });
  console.log(" ~ file: menu.js:112 ~ getDishes ~ response", response);
}
```

I receive error [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 415] --> which is supposedly a bad request.

I am 100% sure that the token is working fine, tried it on postman and works fine.

I have tried to data,config instead of params and still the same issue.

I want to send the categoryId as a parameter in the request body like this while setting the Authorization

with `Bearer${userToken}`

[image]

Comment: HTTP error `415` means `METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED`. Going by the error code, my best guess is you're making a GET call to the API while it doesn't support GET.

Comment: But how is it accepted in postman and not in my code? :/

Comment: Can you share the request made through Postman?

Comment: Sure mate. What is it exactly do you want me to share from postman?

Comment: The console output, comprising of the request, request headers, response and the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Use `data` for a request body. `params` are added to a url.

```
{
...

  // `params` are the URL parameters to be sent with the request
  // Must be a plain object or a URLSearchParams object
  params: {
    ID: 12345
  },

...

  // `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
  // Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE , and 'PATCH'
  // When no `transformRequest` is set, must be of one of the following types:
  // - string, plain object, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, URLSearchParams
  // - Browser only: FormData, File, Blob
  // - Node only: Stream, Buffer, FormData (form-data package)
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred'
  },

...

}
```

See [Request config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) for details.

Comment: much appreciated mate, but it didnt change anything, I still get [AxiosError: Network Error]